# Bind object properties to another object - different type

Tags: c#

I have a class called `ClassMaster` and 4 other classes called `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`, `ClassD` which inherit `ClassMaster`.

```
public class ClassMaster
{
   public ClassMaster()
   {

   } 

   public string PropA {get; set;}
   public string PropB {get; set;}
   public string PropC {get; set;}
   public string PropD {get; set;}
}


public class ClassA: ClassMaster
{
   public ClassA()
   {

   } 
}

public class ClassB: ClassMaster
{
   public ClassB()
   {

   } 
}


public class ClassC: ClassMaster
{
   public ClassC()
   {

   } 
}

public class ClassD: ClassMaster
{
   public ClassD()
   {

   } 
}


ClassMaster cls = new ClassMaster();

ClassA clsA = new ClassA();
ClassB clsB = new ClassB();
ClassC clsC = new ClassC();
ClassD clsC = new ClassD();
```

all my other instances will inherit the ClassMaster properties.

My question is: is there a way to bind the properties of class master instance to other classes instances without? :

```
clsA.PropA = cls.PropA;
```

Why I am asking because in the ClassMaster are about 30 propertie and I would like to know if I can bind them from the master to the inherited ones without writing each time `class.PropertyName = classMaster.PropertyName` ... soemthing like maybe a method: `class.BindYourPropertiesFrom(classMaster)` ...

The `ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD` don't use all properties of ClassMaster ...

P.S.

The scenario is in MVC and azure storage

ClassMaster represent an entity in azure table storage.

Other classess `ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD` are viewmodels in mvc.

ClassMaster represents a task in the application. `ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD` are different types of tasks

Comment: Can you show a real scenario in which you need to do this (with real classes)? Chances are you are approaching the problem wrong if you need to map a `ClassA` to a `ClassMaster`. `ClassA` is already a `ClassMaster`.

Comment: I edited the question and added the scenario

Comment: Based on your scenario, `ClassA` should not be inheriting `ClassMaster` at all - it should be independent. As it stands, your presentation layer is tightly coupled to your data layer. Separate them and use a mapping framework such as Automapper.

Comment: Yep automapper would be a better option.

Comment: So you guys mean that the classes A-D to not inherit ClassMaster and have basically same properties as ClassMaster ... example: if ClassMaster has a property called Name, ClassA should have a Name property also and Automapper will do the trick in mapping them, right?